# Jquery Class change on Href change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've wracked my brain and I'm hopeful someone else has a solution here.

My client wants a menu to fade out and different menu fade in when you go down the page. https://67livingstonst.com/#home then goes to https://67livingstonst.com/#find-story-67-livingston-2

I can't seem to figure out the event they're using... I'm much more adept at Jquery so if anyone has feedback on what event they're using to trigger the menu fading in that would be amazing...

Comment: Please take a moment to review [ask] for details about the information that is expected to be included in a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Tiffany and welcome to Stack overflow. Someone (not me) has downvoted your question because you haven't given an example of what you have already tried, and you have given us links to a fully working site to wade through. Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve See also *How to ask*: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear. Still learning everything to add. This is my current working site that I'm in the midst of dev on: http://stpaullux18re.wpengine.com/

Comment: Look for [haschange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event... It *may be* what you look for.

Comment: I had to make the scroll bar active, which the plugin defaults to hide that function. I Fullpage JS for those looking into it. Then I added this 

$( window ).scroll(function() {
 $( "#standard" ).css( "display", "none" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to change a class when the href changes to match the id of specific slide. I hope this helps!

```
$(window).on("hashchange",function(e){
    if(window.location.hash == "#find-story-67-livingston-2"){
        $("#my-menu").addClass("show");
   } else {
       $("#my-menu").removeClass("show");
   }
})
```

Comment: You can use window scroll event also, although the above answer also will work for you.